# how to run nodemon in js without errores

Tags: nodemon

it give me this error

nodemon : File
C:\Users\sky_cairo\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be
loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon afaf.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecur
  ityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

i try
npm i nodemon
and give me this
up to date, audited 34 packages in 1s

3 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\sky_cairo\OneDrive\Desktop\afaf.js>
then i write nodemon afaf.js
adg give me the error above

Answer (score 0):

in package.json, add this in scripts:

```
"scripts" : {
    "dev" : "nodemon ./afaf.js"
}
```

then in terminal, instead of nodemon afaf.js, run:

```
npm run dev
```